# How are cards dealt when you get Fantasy Land in OFC?

Tags: dealing, open-face-chinese

I know that one card at a time, starting from the left of the button, is dealt out for the first 5 cards in OFC. However, how are cards dealt if someone gets Fantasy Land (FL)? (assuming heads-up play)

Is it the same way, with the first 5 cards dealt one at a time, and then the FL player gets the remaining 8 cards? Or does the non-FL player get dealt 5 cards at once and the FL player all 13 cards at once? Also, is it the same for the case when both players get FL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You deal the cards normally until each player has 5, then the player in FL gets his other 8 cards. If you are playing Pineapple you give the FL player an extra card, which will be his/her's discard card.

Side bit you may also want to know is that a FL hand is technically a continuation of the last hand, which means button does not move while FL occurs.

Comment: I got FL once, and then got it again right away and have no idea how that happened.  Do you ?   I did not have KK+ (the site requirement for FL) when i laid out my FL hand.   I wish I knew how to get 2 in a row,  never seen anyone else do it either.

Comment: Just played pineapple online and can confirm your answer is correct.

Comment: Hey Notorious, it's fairly common for most games of ofc, especially pineapple to allow players to stay in FL. In general the requirements can differ, it is really up to the players. It used to be boat in the back and boat in the middle to stay in FL but most people lowered the requirements. Last I time I dealt Pineapple it was quads+ in the back, or house+ in the middle, or trips up top to return to FL.

Comment: Ahhh, OK, I think that must have been it.  I had quads bottom boat middle, and a pair of 3's on top.   Thanks for the info.  :)